# Probability of picking something (3/10) given three chances?

Tags: probability

You have a slot machine with 3 slots in which symbols can be shown (i.e. vertically) and a rotating wheel with 10 symbols on.

There are 7 different fruit symbols and 3 strawberry symbols, making up the 10 symbols on the wheel.

What is the probability that a strawberry turns up in one of the three slots?

Also the wheel randomly changes its order of symbols each spin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability none of them land on strawberry $(\frac{7}{10}*\frac{6}{9}*\frac{5}{8}) $

Probability at least one lands on strawberry $ 1- \frac{7}{10}*\frac{6}{9}*\frac{5}{8}$

Probability exactly one lands on strawberry $ \frac{7^2*3}{10^3}*3$

Comment: Thanks Rowan, could you please explain why the formulas work? Especially no.2

Comment: for 1) P( first one lands on strawberry) *P( 2nd lands on strawberry) *P( 3rd one lands on strawberry) =7/10 *7/10 *7/10

Comment: for 2) we just have to remove the possibility that none of them lands on strawberry from 1. so we get 1 - (7/10)^3

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Rowan! Please can you explain 3 also?

Comment: Actually if the first slot isn't a stawberry doesn't the next probability have to be reduced i.e. 7/10*6/9*5/8?

Comment: oh yes sorry I'll correct

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as an unfairly weighted coin you are flipping three times.  There is a 3/10 probability of heads and 7/10 probability of tails.
Possible outcomes are:
HHH*

HHT*

HTH*

THH*

HTT*

THT*

TTH*

TTT

(Each outcome where at least one flip ends up with heads is marked with a star)

Remember, P(H) = 3/10, P(T) = 7/10 so the probability of outcome HHH is (3/10)<sup>3</sup> and of HHT is ((3/10)<sup>2</sup>)*(7/10), etc.

Add the probabilities of each favorable outcome and that will give you the probability that at least one slot falls on strawberry.